# DateTimeFormatter Accept Multiple Types and Convert to One

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I am trying to write a `DateTimeFormatter` that will allow me to take in multiple different string formats, and then convert the string formats to a specific type. Due to the scope of the project and the code that already exists, **I cannot use a different type of formatter**.

eg.
I want to accept `MM/dd/yyyy` as well as `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` but then convert both to `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Could someone suggest ideas on how to do this with the `org.joda.time.format`?

I have not found a good/working example of this online.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is but I want to convert a String to a DateTime, ie., DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using **Joda-Time 2.9.7** and **JDK 1.7.0_79**.

You can use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.append` method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#append-org.joda.time.format.DateTimePrinter-org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser:A-): it receives a printer (with a pattern used to print date/times) and an array of parsers with all possible input patterns:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser;

// MM/dd/yyyy format
DateTimeFormatter monthDayYear = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
// array of parsers, with all possible input patterns
DateTimeParser[] parsers = {
    // parser for MM/dd/yyyy format
    monthDayYear.getParser(),
    // parser for yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss format
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").getParser() };
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // use the monthDayYear formatter for output (monthDayYear.getPrinter()) and parsers array for input (parsers)
    .append(monthDayYear.getPrinter(), parsers)
    // create formatter (using UTC to avoid DST problems)
    .toFormatter().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

// test with MM/dd/yyyy
DateTime datetime1 = parser.parseDateTime("06/14/2017");
System.out.println(parser.print(datetime1)); // 06/14/2017

// test with yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
DateTime datetime2 = parser.parseDateTime("2017-06-14T10:30:40");
System.out.println(parser.print(datetime2)); // 06/14/2017
```

I've used `DateTimeZone.UTC` to avoid problems with Daylight Saving Time.

For example, in my default timezone (`America/Sao_Paulo`), last year (2016), DST started at October 16<sup>th</sup>: at midnight, the clocks move 1 hour ahead (so, **tecnically**, midnight doesn't exist at this day, because time changes from `23:59:59` to `01:00:00`).

The problem is, when parsing `MM/dd/yyyy` format, there's no fields for hour, minute or second, and the parser sets `0` as a default value for all these fields (so the hour becomes midnight). But if I try to parse in a date where DST starts (like `10/16/2016`) and don't use the `UTC` as above, the code throws an exception because midnight doesn't exist in that day (due to DST hour shift).

Using `UTC` avoids this error, as `DateTimeZone.UTC` has no DST effects. With this, the code works independent of your system's default timezone.

The output is:

> 06/14/2017
>   06/14/2017

---

**PS:** As you care only about the **date** part (day/month/year), you could also use the `org.joda.time.LocalDate` class. To use it, just change the last part of the code (you can use the same `parser`):

```
// test with MM/dd/yyyy
LocalDate dt1 = parser.parseLocalDate("06/14/2017");
System.out.println(parser.print(dt1)); // 06/14/2017

// test with yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
LocalDate dt2 = parser.parseLocalDate("2017-06-14T10:30:40");
System.out.println(parser.print(dt2)); // 06/14/2017
```

The output is the same:

> 06/14/2017
>   06/14/2017

Using a `LocalDate` is another way to avoid problems with Daylight Saving Time (as explained above). In this case, you don't need to set `UTC`, because `LocalDate` has no timezone information.

Comment: @AlexKornhauser I've updated the answer: making some tests I found some potencial errors with DST, so I fixed the code accordingly.

Comment: How would I do this same exact thing with the java.time library instead, eg DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"); + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

Comment: I don't think the new API has such feature, probably you'll need one formatter to parse the input (use a optional pattern `[MM/dd/yyyy][yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss]`) and another to format the output

Answer (score 2):

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = 
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[MM/dd/yy][M/dd/yy][MM/d/yy][M/d/yy]");

// value = "04/12/19"
// value = "4/12/19"
// value = "12/4/19"
// value = "2/4/19"

LocalDate.parse(value, SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT);
```